# Erro ao carregar extensão mcrypt: extension "mcrypt" must be loaded

Tags: php, ubuntu, magento

Estou tentando instalar o magento localmente porém o mesmo acusa;

> PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.

Já instalei o `curl` e o `gd` porem nada que eu faça para instalar o mcrypt funciona, já tentei...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

e

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install php5-mcrypt
```

E toda vez que tento:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Recebo mensagem de `fail`

Comment: Adicinou uma linha no php.ini para carregar essa ext? assim: `extension=mcrypt.so`, depois não esqueça de reiniciar o apache.

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou? Se não, informe poderia teve alguma duvida no uso dela.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema era na minha distro do linux mesmo, tive que reiniciar para poder validar.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26116628/1518921) no Ubuntu quando usamos `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` ele não instala a extensão na pasta `mods-available`, pra resolver isto será necessário criar um `symlink`, use este comando no terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

Em seguida habilite a extensão usando `php5enmod` e reinicie o Apache:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 reload
```